# Class has no defined attribute

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

I am a complete beginner and trying to model a deck of cards in Python. I keep getting an attribute error saying 'Deck object has no attribute 'cards'. It would seem to me that the Deck class was given the attribute in the **init** function.
Looked up a tutorial on youtube after trying to figure it out and slightly modified my code to match that in the tutorial yet I still get this error. I reread the chapter on classes in my book and I can't for the life of me figure it out.
Thanks.

```
suits = 'Spades Diamonds Clubs Hearts'.split()
val = 'Ace', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King'

    class Card:
        def __init__(self, rank, suit):
            self.rank = rank
            self.suit = suit
    
        def show_card(self):
            print(f"{self.rank} of {self.suit.title()}")
    
    
    class Deck:
    
        def __init__(self):
            self.build_deck()
            self.cards = []
    
        def build_deck(self):
            for v in val:
                for s in suits:
                    self.cards.append(Card(v, s))
            return self.cards
    
    d = Deck()
    print(d.build_deck())
```

Comment: That isn't the error I get, I have `val is not defined`; please share val and suits please. And if you run the exact same code you pasted, you shouldn't have the error you share

Comment: You have many no implmented things. "suit" object and its method "title" and the arrays "val" and "suits"

Comment: @Wender yes, I should have included those in the OP. edited to fix that.

Comment: @azro I included the fix suggested by the poster below and I no longer get the error.
But now the list self.cards gets filled with cards in this format: <__main__.Card object at 0x0111C250>

also thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `build_deck()` before `self.cards` is defined. This is a problem because `build_deck` tries to `self.cards.append`.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.build_deck()
    self.cards = []
```

should be

```
def __init__(self):
    self.cards = []
    self.build_deck()
```